# Error con campo consecutivo en MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

Antes que nada, gracias por leerme.

Estoy agregando datos desde php a una bd y tengo un campo en mi tabla que se tiene que generar consecutivamente, pero cuando elimino algunos campos y agrego uno nuevo, la numeración consecutiva se queda en el ultimo campo que borre, saben si hay forma de arreglarlo(Estoy usando Navicat como gestor).

Y como podría hacer para que ademas del primer campo consecutivo también me genere el segundo que es "PROY000016", ya que ese esta como varchar.

Les dejo una imagen para que se den una idea:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Les agradecería mucho su ayuda.

Comment: No le veo ninguna utilidad a tu segunda columna, al ser un dato que se podría generar de forma dinámica fuera de la base de datos, **cuando se necesite**, combinando la cadena `PROY` con el valor del campo `ID`. No veo qué sentido tendría guardar un dato así, más lo que te costará mantenerlo, debido precisamente a los saltos de `ID` que se pueden apreciar, más el espacio que te va a ocupar. En fin... demasiado trabajo para un campo que parece *vago*: te hace trabajar a ti, y además te obligará a preocuparte de los campos `ID` auto incrementales, mientras que él no hace nada más que `PROY+ID`
.